# How to transfer the data from Data Base to VIEW via PRESENTER?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, linq, mvp

I'm trying to create app that implements MVP pattern using WinForms.

Wherein I'm also using EF+CodeFirst+Linq.

On the **VIEW** there is `DataGridView` control, that need filling a data. The **VIEW** call a method `SELECT()` of **PRESENTER** class, which in turn call a method `SELECT()` of **MODEL** class.

How to transfer the data from Data Base to **VIEW** via **PRESENTER**?

I'm trying to use `return` but it not work because i'm using the `USING` block.

```
internal void Select()
{
    using (GoodsContext context = new GoodsContext())
    {
        var items = from Items in context.Goods
                    select Items;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change return type of `Select` method to `List<Good>`
Then "materialize" result to the List of data, and you will not depend on the `DataContext`

```
internal List<Good> Select()
{
    using (GoodsContext context = new GoodsContext())
    {
        return context.Goods.Select(items => items).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite interesting question. Of course one can materialize the query and return it as `IEnumerable`, but I was wondering what is the way to return it as `IQueryable`, to allow further filtering/sorting etc. The only way I see is to **not** dispose the `DbContext` (apparently the returned queryable keeps reference to it), but is it safe? Then I've googled and found this [Do I always have to call Dispose() on my DbContext objects? Nope](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html). The explanation inside sounds reasonable to me, and we already have a disposable object (`Task`) that we are not supposed to `Dispose`.

Shortly, you can remove the `using` statement and return the `IQueryable`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I'm just new in c# and and not very good at `IQueryable`, `Task`, `Dispose` and etc. Any additional information will be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should change type of method `Select` from `void` to `IEnumerable<Good>` to be able to return something. Also use `.ToList` to materialize result to a `List`:

```
internal IEnumerable<Good> Select()
{
    using (GoodsContext context = new GoodsContext())
    {
        var items = (from Items in context.Goods
                     select Items).ToList();
        return items;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it work well! Thanks! Is that the best way to solve problem?